# My Neuronal Network isn't learning (negative R_Squared, always same loss, categorial input data, regression)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, categorical-data

I try to get my Neuronal Network to work but unfortunately it looks like I am missing something.

I have input data from different categories.
For example the type of a machine. ('abc', 'bcd', 'dca').

So one line of my input contains different words from different distinct word-categories. At the moment I have ~70.000 samples with 12 features.

First I use sklearns labelEncoder to transform every word into a number.
The vocabulary size goes up to 17903.

My simple newtwork looks like this:

```
#Start with the NN

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(np.amax(ml_input)+1, 300, input_length = x_train.shape[1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = tf.keras.activations.linear)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_absolute_error,
              metrics=[R_squared])
model.summary()



#Train the Model
callback = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=5.0, patience=15),
           tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, min_delta=5.00, min_lr=0)
           ]
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50,  batch_size=64, verbose =2, callbacks = callback)
```

The loss of the first epoch is about 120 and after two epochs 70 but now it doesn't change anymore. So after two epochs my net isn't learning anymore.

I already tried other loss functions, standarize my labels (they go from 3 to 500mins), more neurons, another dense layer, another activation function. But after two epochs alway loss of 70. My R_Squared is something like -0.02 it changes but alway stays negative near 0.

It seems like my network isn't learning at all.

Does anyone have an Idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your "vocabulary" your categories? Are you trying to classify your inputs into one of those 17903 words? Or maybe more than one of those words for each input? And typically you only use softmax on the output layer when your output is an N-element vector representing the network's belief that the input lies in each of N categories.

Comment: My vocabulary is every word from every input-category.
The softmax is just an example, i tried a lot of differerent activation-functions but all with the same result. :(